# Printer API does not throw exception

Tags: java

I used Java Printer API to print. My printer is needed to connected by a wire. So, when that cable is not connected (to my PC), PrinterException should be thrown. When I run my program first time, exception is thrown. But at second time, exception is not thrown and program ends normally. After restarting OS, exception is thrown for first time running.

My thinking is it looks like printer jobs are waiting until printer is connected. When I connect the printer, previous data are printed automatically.

I would like to know is what should I add to throw PrinterException whenever printer is disconnected. Now it's only thrown only first time running and I need to restart OS to test behavior.

Here is my code:

```
 PrintService ps = PrinterService.getPrintService(
                printer.getValue());

         PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
        aset.add(new JobName(" - Document", null));
        aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_DESIGNATED_LONG);

        DocPrintJob printjob = ps.createPrintJob();

        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(new PrintableReceipt(mydata),
                DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);
        try
        {
            printjob.print(doc, aset);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        }
        catch (PrintException printerException)
        {
          //  printjob.removePrintJobListener(this);
            printStatus.put("printStatus", false);
            return addCORS(Response.serverError().entity(
                    JSON.encode(printStatus)).build());
        }
```

Comment: Well, I guess your assumption is correct: the jobs are queued even though the printer is not connected. What is your question?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add my question. My question is    "   I would like to know is what should I add to throw PrinterException whenever printer is disconnected. Now it's only thrown only first time running and I need to restart OS to test behavior."

Answer (score 0):

> when that cable is not connected (to my PC), PrinterException should be thrown

That's not what it says in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/DocPrintJob.html#print-javax.print.Doc-javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet-). What it *does* say is this:

> When the print method returns, printing may not yet have completed as printing may happen asynchronously, perhaps in a different thread. Application clients which want to monitor the success or failure should register a `PrintJobListener.`

So do that.

Comment: Yes, I used PrintJobListener. I used two classes, first class contains above code that class implements PrintJobListener. Second class is the class that implements Printable.   For the first class, there are interface methods, such as printJobCompleted(),printJobNoMoreEvents and so on. But when I debug, none of those are invoked. Try block is executed successfully.

Comment: So the job got spooled to the printer queue successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Now, as far as I know is it's because of Java version difference. It's happen when we change Java version from 1.8.0_20 to 1.8.0_51.At earlier version, we can make setting to queue and can catch exception. But at 1.8.0_51, queue became default and cannot modifiable behavior.